# Why my question was put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I don't understand why my question was put on hold. I also replied to an email you sent earlier two days ago, but I have not received any response as yet. It did not allow me to attach a file even its size only 1.7mb. Please let me know.

Thank you,
Loc Le

Comment: Presumably this is in relation to your [previous question, linked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537116/linux-securities)?

Comment: Big files can be uploaded to e.g. DropBox or Google Drive. And you can edit your question to include a **shared** link to the file.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Note that when the image is eventually deleted from the shared drive/cloud storage, this would render the question unclear again and virtually useless for anyone with a possibly similar issue, or for that matter, a good or better answer (if, as in this case, the question _depends_ on the image for clarity). It would be better to use the image upload button in the editing UI and upload an image properly.

Answer (score 11):

[The question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537116/linux-securities) was put on hold as "unclear" (and later automatically deleted as it was never updated).  It is unclear because you failed to include information about the message that you saw on screen.  We generally don't like images in questions, but we recognise that it's sometimes difficult to transcribe text that can't easily be copied and pasted into questions (see e.g. [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086) for a discussion about this).

You seemed to have had difficulties actually inserting the image in you question though, and the original version of the question only contains a path to a compressed `tar` archive.

To insert an image, press the image button in the user interface when editing the question:
[image]

(that's the button to the right of the `{}` button in this screenshot, indicated by the added arrow) Then browse for the image on your system and add it with the controls provided by the website.

Note that you must use an image file, not a compressed `tar` archive.  If the image is big or shows things that are irrelevant for the question, consider cropping it in some type of image editing software before uploading it. Also consider that people (like myself) often find it very difficult to read small text in screenshots.