# Does anyone know a good OCR tool online that we can use for screenshots?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm rather tired of barking at users not to post text as images.  [We all know the reasons why not to do this.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

In the community minded spirit, I wonder if anyone knows a reliable OCR tool that could be used to transcribe screenshots, if not photos as well.

Generally I like the approach of Stack Exchange of letting us edit someone else's question so the we can fix the problem instead of moaning at new users all the time.

Occasionally, the most dedicated users kindly do this manually, but it would be nice if it wasn't so time consuming.

Actually this would make a pretty good feature request,
but I doubt SE will have any appetite to implement it.

---

I think one of the more tricky issues here is finding an OCR tool designed for technical use that understands fixed width spacing.

In an ideal world this should be able to maintain indentation, which many OCR tools are not designed to do.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic for this particular meta StackExchange. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: OCR tools mostly apply to pdf files. When I last time used Google, it was easy to find websites that can convert an image to pdf, and websites that perform OCR on pdf files.

Comment: http://www.djvu.org/index.php?title=Any2DjVu+Server